# HTML canvas drawImage stacks images when changing source

Tags: html, angular, typescript, html5-canvas

I'm trying to show an animation when the user scrolls on my page. I've followed the following guide to make an "Apple like animation", and tried with my own image sequence.
https://css-tricks.com/lets-make-one-of-those-fancy-scrolling-animations-used-on-apple-product-pages/

I've tried my best to adapt the code to something Angular supports, but I'm still quite new to Angular.

But when I scroll through the animation, it is just stacking the next picture on top of the previous ones.

This is the result:

[image]

This is the code I'm using:

```js
ngOnInit(): void {
  const canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement> document.getElementById("canvas1")!;
  const context = canvas.getContext("2d")!;

  canvas.width = 1158;
  canvas.height = 770;

  const img = new Image()
  img.onload = () => {
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
  img.src = this.currentFrame(1);

  window.addEventListener('scroll', () => {
    const scrollLength = window.scrollY;
    const maxScrollTop = this.document.body.scrollHeight - window.innerHeight;
    const scrollFraction = scrollLength / maxScrollTop;
    let frameIndex = Math.min(
      this.frameCount,
      Math.floor(scrollFraction * this.frameCount)
    );
    if (frameIndex + 1 > this.frameCount) frameIndex = this.frameCount + 2;
    requestAnimationFrame(() => this.updateImage(frameIndex, canvas, context, img));
  });
  this.preloadImages();
}

updateImage(index: number, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, img: HTMLImageElement) {
  if (index == 0 || index > this.frameCount) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, img.width , img.height);
  } else {
    img.src = this.currentFrame(index);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was actually the right thought Zorion had with his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72945093/17145317)

But when doing it like that, the canvas will turn blank until the next image had been loaded, making it feel laggy and chuggy. The solution to this is to clear the canvas once the next image had been loaded.

Adding the context.clearRect in the img.onload function:

```js
img.onload = () => {
  context.clearRect(0, 0, img.width , img.height);
  context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to clear it before adding the new image. Try changing this function:

```js
updateImage(index: number, canvas: HTMLCanvasElement, context: CanvasRenderingContext2D, img: HTMLImageElement) {
  if (index == 0 || index > this.frameCount) {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, img.width , img.height);
  } else {
    context.clearRect(0, 0, img.width , img.height);
    img.src = this.currentFrame(index);
    context.drawImage(img, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  }
}
```

Comment: I have already tried this, but it makes it look extremely bad (lagging and making the frame white before displaying every image.